# Deploying Angular 4 With Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular, deployment

I have been building a ruby on rails server, and I have been building an Angular 4 web page.

I would like to deploy my Angular 4 web page and serve it on my Ruby on Rails server.

I have used the command:

```
ng build
```

This has given me a bunch of javascript files and html files.

I have put them into the public folder of my ruby on rails server but I do not know how to serve them on a webpage on my ruby on rails server.

And if this is an unreasonable combination of front end and back end technologies to use, which back end technology would be more appropriate?

Comment: There are many deploy strategies, one of them : http://www.bentedder.com/deploying-angular-4-app-heroku-with-rails-5/

Comment: That guide seems to develop the angular application inside a sub folder of the Ruby on Rails application which isn't what I want.

Comment: I just tried it and it did work (Rails 5 and Angular 7). You also have to delete the root entry from routes.rb file.